# Node.js Module import doesn't Work in one file but in other files

Tags: node.js, events, import, module, undefined

I have a module and created the Object "Event" then I export this Object for other Modules in my application.

But in one of my Modules it doesn't work. The variable in which I want to save it has the value "undefined". I don't understand why.

**Here my Start File [app.js]**

```
console.log('[Server] run...');
require('./SCAN/Scan');
require('./eventHandler/eventHandler');
require('./database/database');
require('./socket-server/socket-server');
require('./scanner/scanner');
```

**in this file I create the Event Object**

```
require('./eventHandler/eventHandler');
```

**content from eventHandler**

```
console.log('[Server] eventHandler.js loaded!');
let io = require('./../socket-server/socket-server').io_ex;
let Event = new ( require('events').EventEmitter)();
  
exports.EventEmitter_ex = Event;
```

**File socket-server:**

```
console.log('[Server] socket-server.js loaded!');

let Scan = require('./../SCAN/Scan').Scan_ex;

// create Server and listen on Port 8181
let app = require('express')();
let server = require('http').Server(app).listen(8181);
let io = require('socket.io')(server);
let EventEmitter = require('./../eventHandler/eventHandler').EventEmitter_ex;

io.on('connection', function (socket) {

    console.log('[Socket] User Connected!');
    if (!Scan.j > 0) {
        return
    }
    
    // do if user connect

    socket.on('fetchData', function () {
        socket.emit('getFetch', Scan);
        socket.emit('newStatus', Scan.status);
        console.log('[Socket] getFetch Send!');
    });
    
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log('[Socket] User Disconnect');
    });
    
    //User Registering

    socket.on('register_user', function (userData) {
        let regExp = /^[A-Za-z0-9]*[A-Za-z0-9]$/;
        console.log('[APP - Registrierung] - Registrierung empfangen!');
        if (!regExp.test(userData.username) && !regExp.test(userData.passwort)) {
            console.log('[APP - Registrierung] - Fehlerhafte Daten von UserData');
            return
        }

        let name = userData.username.toString();
        let passwort = userData.passwort.toString();
        let deviceID = userData.uuid.toString();

        let user = {
            u_name: name,
            u_password: passwort,
            u_uuid: deviceID
        };
    });
});
//----------------------------
exports.io_ex = io;
```

**why is the import Undefined in:**

```
let EventEmitter = require('./../eventHandler/eventHandler').EventEmitter_ex;
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you require the *socket-server* module from the *eventHandler* module. This means that the *socket-server* module initializes before the *eventHandler* module has set the value of its *EventEmitter_ex* export.